# ¿Cómo obtener tickets de un usuario en especifico con mongoose-paginate?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, backend, vite

Esta es la información que esta guardando mi base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se esta guardando un objeto con la información del usuario que solicito el ticket, necesito traerme los ticket del usuario, como accedo o como puedo poner la condición dentro de find para poder obtener estos datos

Esta es la consulta que estoy haciendo:

```
export const getTickets = async (req, res) => {
  const { user } = req;
  const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = req.query;

  const options = {
    page: parseInt(page),
    limit: parseInt(limit),
    sort: { createdAt: "desc" },
  };


  // Verify permissions
  if (
    !user.permissions.includes("admin") &&
    !user.profiles.includes("support")
  ) {
    await Ticket.paginate(
      {
        "user._id": user._id,
      },
      options,
      (error, tickets) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            response: "error",
            msg: "Server error",
            type: "server-error",
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json(tickets);
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    await Ticket.paginate({}, options, (error, tickets) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          response: "error",
          msg: "Server error",
          type: "server-error",
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json(tickets);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Además, que has intentado? como está tu consulta actual para los tickets del usuario?

Comment: Dentro de que `find`?? Donde esta eso?? Sobreentendemos que es una consulta, pero necesitamos ver que has probado tu y en donde estas teniendo inconvenientes.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta quiero obtener los tickets dependiendo del usuario de la sesión, si no es un usuario admin o de soporte que solo muestre los tickets de dicho usuario si es un admin o de soporte que muestre todos los tickets totales.